# Why is there a shaded red box around some usernames, and not others?

Tags: support

Some users (including myself) have a shaded red box around their usercard.

[image]

But this only happens for certain questions/answers. For instance:

#### Myself:

- red box: [How to identify ancient KornShell version?](https://serverfault.com/q/884546/184613)
- no red box: https://serverfault.com/a/701644/184613

#### Different user:

- red box: [Is there a way to set multiple ZFS filesystem properties at once?](https://serverfault.com/q/807999/184613)
- no red box: https://serverfault.com/a/923243/184613

Is this related to who asks the question? It looks like the red box does not show up for answer-ers, with the exception of those who answered their own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess: The red shade is used for the original poster of the question, both in the question and in answers. As you also guessed.

Comment: Notice that if you look at the edit history for an answer the color is used for the user who wrote the answer not the user who wrote the question.